# How to handle Nested Flux and Monos

Tags: java, spring-webflux, project-reactor, reactive-streams

My data is stored in Cosmos and it is Hierarchical and stored in different tables.

```
Hiearchy of Data
OnBoardingDefinition -> List<FeatureOrder>
FeatureStepMappingDefinition -> List<Steps>
OnBoardingStepDefinition -> Step details
```

When I call cosmos I get Flux>, Flux> & Flux>. I need to construct a complete OnBoarding object which will have all details of Ids.

```
Optional<Flux<OnBoardingDefinition>> onBoardingDefinitionFlux = cosmosRepository.getCosmosDocuments(---);
Optional<Flux<FeatureStepMappingDefinition>> featureStepMappingDefinitionFlux = cosmosRepository.getCosmosDocuments(---);
Optional<Flux<OnBoardingStepDefinition>> onBoardingStepDefinitionFlux = cosmosRepository.getCosmosDocuments(----);

Flux<Flux<Mono<StepResponseDto>>> flux3 = onBoardingDefinitionFlux.get()
            .map(onBoardingDefinition -> onBoardingDefinition.getFeatureOrder())
            .flatMap(Flux::fromIterable)
            .filter(featureOrder -> features.contains(featureOrder.getFeatureCode()) && Objects.nonNull(featureOrder.getRequired()) && featureOrder.getRequired())
            .map(featureOrder ->
                {
                    return getFromFeature(featureStepMappingDefinitionFlux, onBoardingStepDefinitionFlux, featureOrder);
                }
            );


private Flux<Mono<StepResponseDto>> getFromFeature(Optional<Flux<FeatureStepMappingDefinition>> featureStepMappingDefinitionFlux, Optional<Flux<OnBoardingStepDefinition>> onBoardingStepDefinitionFlux, FeatureOrder featureOrder) {
    Flux<Mono<StepResponseDto>> flux1 = featureStepMappingDefinitionFlux.get()
        .filter(featureStepMappingDefinition -> featureStepMappingDefinition.getFeatureCode().equalsIgnoreCase(featureOrder.getFeatureCode()))
        .map(featureStepMappingDefinition -> featureStepMappingDefinition.getSteps())
        .flatMap(Flux::fromIterable)
        .map(step ->
            {
                return getStepResponseDtoMono(onBoardingStepDefinitionFlux, step);
            }
        );
    return flux1;
}

private Mono<StepResponseDto> getStepResponseDtoMono(Optional<Flux<OnBoardingStepDefinition>> onBoardingStepDefinitionFlux, Step step) {
    Mono<StepResponseDto> flux2 = onBoardingStepDefinitionFlux.get()
        .filter(onBoardingStepDefinition -> Objects.nonNull(onBoardingStepDefinition.getActive()) && onBoardingStepDefinition.getActive() && onBoardingStepDefinition.getStepCode().equalsIgnoreCase(step.getStepCode()))
        .map(onBoardingStepDef -> getStepResponseDto(onBoardingStepDef)).next();
    return flux2;
}
```

I need to simplify the above process to avoid nested Flux & Monos. I tried multiple approaches but they didn't work. I have created sample code and output which I am expecting using Flux. I have created using Java 8 the same I want to achieve using Flux.

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Arrays;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.UUID;
    import java.util.stream.Collectors;
    import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;

    //Sample code
    public class MRE {

        public static class Step {
            private String stepCode;
            private Boolean active;
            private String name;

            public Step(String stepCode, Boolean active, String name) {
                this.stepCode = stepCode;
                this.active = active;
                this.name = name;
            }

            public Boolean getActive() {
                return active;
            }

            public void setActive(Boolean active) {
                this.active = active;
            }

            public String getStepCode() {
                return stepCode;
            }

            public void setStepCode(String stepCode) {
                this.stepCode = stepCode;
            }

            public String getName() {
                return name;
            }

            public void setName(String name) {
                this.name = name;
            }

            @Override
            public String toString() {
                return "Step{" +
                    "stepCode='" + stepCode + '\'' +
                    ", active=" + active +
                    ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                    '}';
            }
        }

        public static class Steps {
            private String stepCode;

            public Steps(String stepCode) {
                this.stepCode = stepCode;
            }

            public String getStepCode() {
                return stepCode;
            }

            public void setStepCode(String stepCode) {
                this.stepCode = stepCode;
            }

            @Override
            public String toString() {
                return "Steps{" +
                    "stepCode='" + stepCode + '\'' +
                    '}';
            }
        }

        public static class FeatureStepMapping {
            public FeatureStepMapping(String featureCode, List<Steps> steps) {
                this.featureCode = featureCode;
                this.steps = steps;
            }

            private String featureCode;
            private List<Steps> steps = new ArrayList<>();

            public String getFeatureCode() {
                return featureCode;
            }

            public void setFeatureCode(String featureCode) {
                this.featureCode = featureCode;
            }

            public List<Steps> getSteps() {
                return steps;
            }

            public void setSteps(List<Steps> steps) {
                this.steps = steps;
            }

            @Override
            public String toString() {
                return "FeatureStepMapping{" +
                    "featureCode='" + featureCode + '\'' +
                    ", steps=" + steps +
                    '}';
            }
        }

        public static class StepResponse {
            private String stepCode;
            private String name;

            public StepResponse(String stepCode, String name) {
                this.stepCode = stepCode;
                this.name = name;
            }

            public String getStepCode() {
                return stepCode;
            }

            public void setStepCode(String stepCode) {
                this.stepCode = stepCode;
            }

            public String getName() {
                return name;
            }

            public void setName(String name) {
                this.name = name;
            }

            @Override
            public String toString() {
                return "StepResponse{" +
                    "stepCode='" + stepCode + '\'' +
                    ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                    '}';
            }
        }


        public static class OnBoarding {
            private List<String> featureCodes = new ArrayList<>();

            public OnBoarding(List<String> featureCodes) {
                this.featureCodes = featureCodes;
            }

            public List<String> getFeatureCodes() {
                return featureCodes;
            }

            public void setFeatureCodes(List<String> featureCodes) {
                this.featureCodes = featureCodes;
            }

            @Override
            public String toString() {
                return "OnBoarding{" +
                    "featureCodes=" + featureCodes +
                    '}';
            }
        }

        public static class OnBoardingResponse {
            private String id;
            private List<StepResponse> stepResponses = new ArrayList<>();

            public OnBoardingResponse(String id, List<StepResponse> stepResponses) {
                this.id = id;
                this.stepResponses = stepResponses;
            }

            public String getId() {
                return id;
            }

            public void setId(String id) {
                this.id = id;
            }

            public List<StepResponse> getStepResponses() {
                return stepResponses;
            }

            public void setStepResponses(List<StepResponse> stepResponses) {
                this.stepResponses = stepResponses;
            }

            @Override
            public String toString() {
                return "OnBoardingResponse{" +
                    "id='" + id + '\'' +
                    ", stepResponses=" + stepResponses +
                    '}';
            }
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            Step step1 = new Step("S1", true, "Step1");
            Step step2 = new Step("S2", true, "Step2");
            Step step3 = new Step("S3", true, "Step3");

            List<Step> stepList = Arrays.asList(step1, step2, step3);
            Flux<List<Step>> stepFlux = Flux.just(stepList);


            FeatureStepMapping featureStepMapping1 = new FeatureStepMapping("f1", new ArrayList<>());
            featureStepMapping1.getSteps().add(new Steps("S1"));
            featureStepMapping1.getSteps().add(new Steps("S2"));

            FeatureStepMapping featureStepMapping2 = new FeatureStepMapping("f2", new ArrayList<>());
            featureStepMapping1.getSteps().add(new Steps("S3"));

            List<FeatureStepMapping> featureStepMappingList = Arrays.asList(featureStepMapping1, featureStepMapping2);
            Flux<List<FeatureStepMapping>> stepFeature = Flux.just(featureStepMappingList);


            List<OnBoarding> onBoardingList = Arrays.asList(new OnBoarding(Arrays.asList("f1", "f2")));
            Flux<List<OnBoarding>> onBoardingFlux = Flux.just(onBoardingList);

            // Get Mono<OnBoardingResponse> Don't change Flux<List<>> assume this is I get from database directly.

            //With Plain Java8
            List<StepResponse> stepResponses = onBoardingList.stream().flatMap(onBoarding -> onBoarding.getFeatureCodes().stream())
            .map(feature ->
                featureStepMappingList.stream()
                    .filter(featureStep -> featureStep.getFeatureCode().equalsIgnoreCase(feature))
                    .map(obj -> obj.getSteps()).flatMap(step -> step.stream()).collect(Collectors.toList())
            ).flatMap(obj -> obj.stream())
                .map(step -> stepList.stream().filter(definedStep -> definedStep.getStepCode().equalsIgnoreCase(step.getStepCode())).collect(Collectors.toList()))
            .flatMap(step -> step.stream()).map(step -> new StepResponse(step.getStepCode(), step.getName())).collect(Collectors.toList());

            OnBoardingResponse onBoardingResponse = new OnBoardingResponse(UUID.randomUUID().toString(), stepResponses);

            System.out.println(onBoardingResponse);
        }
    }

//Output 
OnBoardingResponse{id='77b647c5-84ae-4fde-8039-ea5deed1a2bd', stepResponses=[StepResponse{stepCode='S1', name='Step1'}, StepResponse{stepCode='S2', name='Step2'}, StepResponse{stepCode='S3', name='Step3'}]}
```

Comment: The first thing I'd usually do is to try to extract steps as methods. Your `map(featureOrder ->` looks like a good candidate.

Comment: Initially, I created a Map of FeatureCode and Feature but my main issue is how to handle nested Flux and Monos. Once that is resolved I can extract them as methods. I have extracted as methods.

Comment: Wrapping flux/mono in optional is redundant, passing Optional/Mono/Flux as arguments is heavily discouraged, same for wrapping mono in flux and vice versa except in specific advanced cases.

Comment: I actually can't even follow the logic of this, can you post an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) where you aren't using a ton of hidden methods?

Comment: @123 Added sample code.

Comment: Some real gems here. `.flatMap(Flux::fromIterable)` for example. Clearly either completely lost or just making this stuff up. This is not representative and reactive coding or typical problems.

Comment: @K.Nicholas Very constructive

Comment: @cody123 Cheers I'll have a look later

Comment: Why is the database returning `Flux<List<>>` ? A Flux is basically a reactive list, are you creating these entities your self, as no packages I know of would do this?

Comment: Actually this is part of Azure Cosmos SDK it returns a list of data. I have 3 containers in Azure and I call APIs to get data that's why I created 3 Flux. 
- Onboarding
- Feature Step Mapping
- Step Definitions

Comment: Do you create the flux though? I can't imagine cosmos SDK returns `Flux<List<>>`

Comment: Also should all three steps not be in the response?

Comment: It returns Flux<FeedResponse<CosmosItemProperties>>. FeedResponse<CosmosItemProperties> is a list of data. Nope, onboarding will tell what features are part and each feature will have what all steps it has. Steps is a list of onboarding steps so I filter on the basis of Ids and in final returns steps which are part of onboarding.

Comment: Do you have a link to the documentation for it, just actually curious to see.

Comment: Also are you sure, you include both `f1`,`f2` in `onBoardingList` and those feature id's are across the two `FeatureStepMapping`'s, which between them contain all three steps?

Comment: Also I assumed `featureStepMapping1.getSteps().add(new Steps("S3"));` was a typo and should be `featureStepMapping2`

Comment: Dont return `Optional<FluxT>` skip the optional. If there is no result you return a `Flux.empty()` instead. Wrapping fluxes in optionals is unecassary

Comment: Nevermind didn't see `StepResponse{stepCode='S3', name='Step3'}]` on the end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using you example you could do something similar to this to prevent nesting

```
    Flux<Step> stepFlux = Flux.just(
            new Step("S1", true, "Step1"),
            new Step("S2", true, "Step2"),
            new Step("S3", true, "Step3"));

    FeatureStepMapping featureStepMapping1 = new FeatureStepMapping("f1", new ArrayList<>());
    featureStepMapping1.getSteps().add(new Steps("S1"));
    featureStepMapping1.getSteps().add(new Steps("S2"));

    FeatureStepMapping featureStepMapping2 = new FeatureStepMapping("f2", new ArrayList<>());
    featureStepMapping2.getSteps().add(new Steps("S3"));

    Flux<FeatureStepMapping> stepFeature = Flux.just(featureStepMapping1,featureStepMapping2);
    Flux<OnBoarding> onBoarding = Flux.just(new OnBoarding(Arrays.asList("f1", "f2")));

    onBoarding
            .map(OnBoarding::getFeatureCodes)
            //Convert flux to be flux of the feature codes
            .flatMap(Flux::fromIterable)
            //Create tuple matching every feature code to every stepFeature
            //Effectively the same as nested lists
            .join(stepFeature,s -> Flux.never(),s -> Flux.never(),Tuples::of)
            //filter out features that don't match
            .filter(t -> t.getT2().getFeatureCode().equalsIgnoreCase(t.getT1()))
            //Convert flux back to just stepFeatures
            .map(Tuple2::getT2)
            //Convert flux to list of steps
            .map(FeatureStepMapping::getSteps)
            //Convert to individual steps from list
            .flatMap(Flux::fromIterable)
            //Same as before but with stepFlux
            .join(stepFlux,s -> Flux.never(),s -> Flux.never(),Tuples::of)
            .filter(t -> t.getT2().getStepCode().equalsIgnoreCase(t.getT1().getStepCode()))
            //Probably get the point by now
            .map(Tuple2::getT2)
            //Create step responses 
            .map(step -> new StepResponse(step.getStepCode(), step.getName()))
            //Collect to Mono<List<StepResponse>>
            .collectList()
            //Create onboarding response
            .map(stepList -> new OnBoardingResponse(UUID.randomUUID().toString(),stepList))
            //Don't have to subscribe, return to whatever or do whatever with resultant Mono
            //Just to see result as don't know your intentions
            .subscribe(System.out::println);
```

Also if you genuinely get `Flux<List<>>` you can convert to a normal Flux by using

```
fluxList.flatMap(Flux::fromIterable)
```

Comment: It worked like charm. Could you please share me some resources so I can learn more about react. I started few days back.

Comment: @cody123 You can use https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference for a lot of the basic stuff. Everything else I just look at the source code, it's suprisingly well commented for the higher functions.